# Discord.js how to make the bot insert the thing the user sent into an url?

Tags: discord.js

I want to do a namemc bot, where a User says **track (Username)** and it shows the Namemc profile.
To do that i want to insert the text the user told the bot to into an url. This is my code

```
    const saymsg = message.content;
    message.channel.send(`https://namemc.com/profile/**saymsg**.1`)
```

but how can i make the saymsg const show inside of the url?

Answer (score 0):

Split the message content by a space, grab the last element of the array, then insert into the string with template literals.

```
const saymsg = message.content.split(' ')[1];

message.channel.send(`https://namemc.com/profile/${saymsg}.1`);
```